# jquery.cookies not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to establish a cookie

Everything works well but in IE7 & IE8

Here is my JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(function() {
          if (jQuery.cookie('shownDialog') != 'true') {
            window.onload = document.getElementById('lightbox-22556401244951').click(); 
          }
            jQuery.cookie('shownDialog', 'true', {expires: 7});
    });

});
```

Not sure why its not working in only IE7 & IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrapping everything in the ready function so `window.onload` has already fired. Update your code to this:

```
    jQuery(function() {
          if (jQuery.cookie('shownDialog') != 'true') {
            jQuery('#lightbox-22556401244951').trigger("click"); 
          }
            jQuery.cookie('shownDialog', 'true', {expires: 7});
    });
```

Comment: No, the `ready` event happens when the document is loaded, and the `load` event happens when also all content in the document is loaded. The `ready` event normally happens before the `load` event, except sometimes in IE as jQuery has to emulate it. Running the code immediately will make it run before the `load` event.

Answer (score 0):

The `ready` event normally happens before the `load` event, but IE doesn't have an `ondomready` event so jQuery emulates it. That means that the `ready` event sometimes can happen after the `load` event in IE.

Use the `load` method to bind the event, then it will always fire. If the `load` event has already fired, jQuery will call the event handler directly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
      if (jQuery.cookie('shownDialog') != 'true') {
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
          document.getElementById('lightbox-22556401244951').click();
        });
      }
        jQuery.cookie('shownDialog', 'true', {expires: 7});
  });

});
```